# In React, how can I create a flexible array of selected items, using checkboxes, similar to selecting images on my Phone?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase

I am basically looking to recreate this I have recorded on my phone:

[image]

**However, one slight difference:**

I want to max amount of selected items to be, for example, 5. If you have already checked 5 items and check another, it will replace `array[0]` with the one you just selected. If you select another, it will replace `array[1]` and so on.

> In my case, Users have "medals" (basically like achievements in a game). They can choose 5 "medals" to display on their profile.

The window in which users can view all the medals they own and select them so far looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
//#####################################################################
import classNames from "classnames/bind";
//#####################################################################
import { useAuth } from "../../../../contexts/AuthContext";
import { useUser } from "../../../../contexts/UserContext";
//#####################################################################
import { db } from "../../../../firebase.js";
//#####################################################################
import "./ProfileEditMedalShowcase.scss";
//#####################################################################
function ProfileEditMedalShowcase() {
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //STATES
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //This stores data about the user (name, username, bio, profilePicture, ID's of medals unlocked so far)
  const { userData } = useUser();
  //This will store the array of all the medals that have been unlocked so far by the user.
  const [userMedals, setUserMedals] = useState([]);
  //This stores the medals the user wants to put on "showcase". These medals will show on their profile. (Ideally want to limit this to a length of 5).
  const [selectedMedals, setSelectedMedals] = useState([]);
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //USE EFFECTS
  //-------------------------------------------------------

  //When the component loads:
  // 1) Set the user medals to an empty array, in case of refresh or re-render.
  // 2) We already have an array of the medal id's that the user has unlocked. So we need to go get those medals data (image, medal title etc.)
  // 3) The user already have some medals selected to be on show, so prefill the selected medals with them.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (userData) {
      setUserMedals([]);
      getUserMedalsData(userData.medals);
      setSelectedMedals(userData.medalShowcase);
    }
  }, [userData]);
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //METHODS
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //Get the data of the medals that the user owns from firebase (medals have titles, images etc.).
  async function getUserMedalsData(medals) {
    const snapshot = await db.collection("medals").get();
    snapshot.docs.forEach((medal) => {
      if (medals.includes(medal.id)) {
        setUserMedals((existingMedals) => [...existingMedals, medal.data()]);
      }
    });
  }
  //This is where I am currently trying to add/remove medals, not yet tackled the issue of overwriting if length is > 5.
  function addRemoveSelectedMedal(medal) {
    if (!selectedMedals.includes(medal)) {
      const tempArray = selectedMedals;
      tempArray.push(medal);
      setSelectedMedals(tempArray);
    } else {
      const removedMedal = selectedMedals.filter(
        (existingMedal) => existingMedal === medal
      );
      console.log("removed medal array: ", removedMedal);
      setSelectedMedals(removedMedal);
    }
  }
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  //END
  //-------------------------------------------------------
  return (
    <div className="profileEditMedalShowcase">
      <h4>Choose Medals To Showcase</h4>
      {/* Here we map through the medals that may already be selected to be highlighted and display them.*/}
      <div className="profileEditMedalShowcase__selectedMedals">
        {selectedMedals.length > 0 ? (
          selectedMedals.map((medal) => {
            <span
              key={medal.medalTitle}
              className="profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem"
            >
              <img
                src={medal.medalDownloadUrl}
                className="profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem__medal"
                alt={medal.medalTitle}
              />
            </span>;
          })
        ) : (
          <h4>No Medals Selected</h4>
        )}
      </div>
      {/* Here we map through all the medals that the user has unlocked, so they can choose which ones they want to showcase.*/}
      {userMedals.length > 0 && (
        <div className="profileEditMedalShowcase__gridContainer">
          {userMedals.map((medal, index) => (
            <span
              key={medal.medalTitle}
              className="profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem"
              className={
                selectedMedals.includes(medal)
                  ? "profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem medalSelected"
                  : "profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem"
              }
            >
              <img
                src={medal.medalDownloadUrl}
                className="profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem__medal"
                alt={medal.medalTitle}
              />
              {/* This is a checkbox that will basically add or remove the medal from the showcase array.*/}
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                name="showcaseMedals"
                className="profileEditMedalShowcase__medalGridItem__checkbox"
                value={medal}
                onChange={() => {
                  addRemoveSelectedMedal(medal);
                }}
              />
            </span>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProfileEditMedalShowcase;
```

So far it does not work. Plus I am confused over the logic on how to go about this. It seems quite involved and Im just wondering if somebody has the logic down?

TIA Guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to max amount of selected items to be, for example, 5. If you have already checked 5 items and check another, it will replace array[0] with the one you just selected. If you select another, it will replace array[1] and so on.

you're looking for a FIFO (first in, first out) array logic, here's an example of a function to accomplish this.

```js
function addFifo(array, elementToAdd, maxCount) {
  if (array.length >= maxCount) {
    // remove first element of the array
    array.shift();
  }
  // add element at the end of the array
  array.push(elementToAdd);
}
```

if you don't want to alter your original array:

```js
function addFifo(array, elementToAdd, maxCount) {
  // clone array
  const result = array.concat();
  if (result.length >= maxCount) {
    result.shift();
  }
  // add element to the end and return array
  return result.concat(elementToAdd);
}
```

in your code you could do that:

```js
function addRemoveSelectedMedal(medal) {
    if (!selectedMedals.includes(medal)) {
        const newSelection = selectedMedals.concat();
        if (newSelection.length >= 5) {
            newSelection.shift();
        }
        newSelection.push(medal);
        setSelectedMedals(newSelection);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

you can go further and wrap your function and logic in a useCallback + mutator function for the update:

```js
const addRemoveSelectedMedal = React.useCallback(medal => {
    setSelectedMedals(selectedMedals => {
        if (!selectedMedals.includes(medal)) {
            const newSelection = selectedMedals.concat();
            if (newSelection.length >= 5) {
                newSelection.shift();
            }
            newSelection.push(medal);
            return newSelection;
        } else {
            return selectedMedals.filter(
                existingMedal => existingMedal !== medal
            );
        }
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi man, first of all thanks a bunch for replying. Really great answers thank you. Your original solution works great, I just need to figure out removing an item from its specific position should the user uncheck a medal thats checked, so will try that now. Didn't even know about array.shift, so thank you!

Comment: As for the second edit, could you give a quick reason why useCallback is useful here, as I am still quite new and don't know what its use it. I will research useCallback now, but just wondering in my context why you recommend it? No doubt it will be a great addition, just want to make sure I understand it!

Comment: useCallback will avoid recreating the function at each render (as if it was declared in the global scope). Having stable function references across your app is great to marginally improve performances (depends on app size) and avoid some tricky bugs. I'd need a full blog post to explain in-depth but basically it's not a big deal, just a small bonus.

Comment: Ah thats great, will definitely implement that now. Thanks a bunch for the help. Will mark answer as correct now. 



Thanks a bunch!

Comment: hm for some reason, when I uncheck an item, the array.filter() removes the first item in the array, not the one I unchecked. I'll add an edit of a GIF of what it looks like. console logging the medal that was unchecked is correct. very confusing. sorry to bother you again!

Comment: Never mind ive fixed it! the filter should of been 

return selectedMedals.filter(
          (existingMedal) => existingMedal !== medal
        );

So it brings back all the medals except the one that was unchecked. Before it was doing the reverse. Thank you @Apolo !